# Scroll Magic - Multiple of the Same Animation

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

Getting my feet wet with ScrollMagic. I have a bunch of elements on a page:

```
<section id="section1">
    <!-- .... -->
</section>

<section id="section2">
    <!-- .... -->
</section>

<section id="section3">
    <!-- .... -->
</section>
```

And I would like to trigger the same animation on each of them as they scroll into view. It works fine for one, but would I have to duplicate this code 3 times, seems like I'm missing something that would allow me to just apply a single instance across all 3.

```
// Init ScrollMagic Controller
var scrollMagicController = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// Create Animation for 0.5s
var tween = TweenMax.to('#section2 DIV', 0.5, {
    //backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 39, 46)',
    top: '-100px',
    opacity: 1
    });

// Create the Scene and trigger when visible
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#section2',
    triggerHook: 1,
    duration: 300,

    //reverse: false,

    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(scrollMagicController);

// Add debug indicators fixed on right side
scene.addIndicators();
```

Comment: how about iterating with [jQuery's .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) ?